# Run a command when a player first joins a server

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, server-administration

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a way to run a command on every player who joins the server *for the first time*.  Is this possible with a vanilla CS:GO server, or is there a plugin required to do this?

For example:

```
NewPlayer is joining the Terrorist force
Server: /freeze <player> 10
NewPlayer has been frozen for 10 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this with a Vanilla server.

Then again, /freeze isn't a stock command anyway, so you should be able to find a server plugin to run commands like this.  However, one that specifically only runs commands on players the first time ever they join a server may not yet be written.